# How can I pipe from fluent-ffmpeg to AWS s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, fluent, node-streams

I'm trying:

```
        const passthroughStream = new PassThrough()
        ffmpeg(stream).audioBitrate(8)
            .output(passthroughStream, { end: true })
            .on('progress', (p) => console.log(p))
            .on('error', (err) => console.log(err))

        const bucketStreamParams = {
            Bucket: 'mybucket',
            Key: outputFilename,
            Body: passthroughStream
        }

        const s3Response = await s3.upload(bucketStreamParams).promise()
```

But nothing seems to happen. I thought the `PassThrough` would handle this, but it doesn't seem to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are not waiting for the ffmpeg to finish, then how can you send that to S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add a `.format` and then it worked:

```
        ffmpeg(stream)
            .format('mp3')
            .output(passthroughStream, { end: true })
            .on('error', (err) => console.log(err))
            .run()
```