# Is there any way to upload fluent-ffmpeg converted videos directly to s3 without storing them on local?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fluent-ffmpeg

Is it possible to store ffmpeg output directly to s3 without downloading it in local or any other storage?
Below is my understanding of ffmpeg which converts format of video. I have done conversion part but i need to store it's output directly to s3 bucket so anyone have idea regarding this problem ?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const axios = require('axios');


const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: 's3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',   // Put you region
    accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,       // Put you accessKeyId
    secretAccessKey: S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,   // Put you accessKeyId
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,         // Put your bucket name
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'ap-south-1'           // Put you region
});

var params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Delimiter: '',
    Prefix: S3_STORE_PATH
};
s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    data.Contents.forEach(function (obj, index) {
        const file_name = obj.Key;
        const type = "mp4";
        console.log(obj.Key)
        const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: obj.Key,
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
        });
        console.log("SIGNED URL= ", url);
        const filename = file_name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
        const localFileOutput = `${filename}.${type}`;
        // const localFileOutput = `${bucket_url}${filename}.${type}`;
        console.log(localFileOutput);
        const key = `${filename}.${type}`;
        const convert_video = async (req,res) => {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                ffmpeg().input(url)
                    .toFormat('mp4')
                    .output(localFileOutput)
                    .on('end', async () => {
                        const params = {
                            Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
                            Key: key,
                            Body: localFileOutput
                        }
                        // const fileContent = await fs.readFileSync(localFileOutput);
                        await s3.putObject(params).promise();
                        resolve();
                    }).run();
            });

            // res.send("success")
        }
        convert_video();
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pipe from fluent-ffmpeg to AWS s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620261/how-can-i-pipe-from-fluent-ffmpeg-to-aws-s3)

Comment: For the general case:  No.  Some containers require seeking during output, which isn't possible with a stream-to-S3 solution.  If you can control the container and options for it, it might be possible.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Yes you're correct they did same thing but for mp3 format and in my case i need mp4 format and for that format it's not working as they mentioned